Do we need a tag for meta-psychological questions, and what could it be named?
Maybe I'm alone with this, but I'm very much interested in the history, philosophy of science, sociology, and educational practices of our sciences.
Why do we research what we research, and not something else? Why do we use these methods and not others? How did this come about, and what is the status of the segregated traditions? How does an education as a psychologist shape the personality of the psychologist? Why do psychologists not implement their knowledge into their pedagogical teaching practice? etc.
What I miss, is a tag for these kinds of questions. I wouldn't know what to name it.
What is your opinion?

I am totally game for such questions, but as many on here know I am an inclusionist, and I expect other members will disagree with me.

I like the idea. Are there several existing questions on the site that would receive the tag?

For what it is worth, I like the idea also.

A few possible tags 

"history-of-psychology" This could be for questions about the historical development of the field. Update: I added this to your question history-of-psychology subject to there being no major objections by others.
"philosophy-of-science" or "philosophy-of-psychology" for philosophical questions about psychology: e.g., the logic of empiricism, theory building, epistemology as it relates psychology, etc.

I would also like to have tags that relate to professionals working in psychology:
 "teaching-psychology" for questions about teaching psychology at high school or university level (correction; we already now have the teaching teaching-of-psychology tag for this purpose)
We do have the publication-process tag for questions about publishing in psychology, selecting journals, peer review, issues around open access, citations, and so on
There are also a range of topics that relate to being a scientist or academic or phd student in psychology and the cognitive sciences. There is the site academia.stackexchange.com but I often find that the advice is general and that it would be good to be able to ask questions that were more psychology specific.
General idea for tags
In general, I think it's easier to justify the creation of a tag if:
You can point to at least three existing questions that would be better linked and well served by the creation of such a tag. That shows that (a) there is a need for the tag (b) that such questions are on topic for the site, and (c) makes it concrete how the tag might be useful.

While I dont frequent Cog Sci, [tag:teaching-psychology] sounds like a pretty bad idea. With slight rephrasing, a lot of self-help questions could make it to the site under that banner.

I guess I'm thinking about the kinds of topics dealt with by Division 2 of the APA http://teachpsych.org/ . I.e., Scientific questions about how to teach psychology. What kind of self-help questions were you thinking of? e.g., "I'm a teacher and I need a video to demonstrate psychology topic X?"

"I am  a teacher and I would like to demonstrate in class how instant gratification can be detrimental to long term goals. How would I be able to this? Also, what can I do to minimize the lure of instant gratification on my students and make them more persistent?" == "I tend to choose instant gratification rather than working hard and learning on many problems that I face daily. What can I do to reduce its effects or lure, and become more persistent?"

I think there is a difference between the psychology of teaching ([tag:teaching]) and the academic education of future psychologists (possibly [tag:teaching-of-psychology] or [tag:psychological-education]).

I agree. At the moment we have "educational-psychology" for teaching questions. and the teaching tag is purely for "teaching-of-psychology" type questions. That said, I think it is a bit confusing, and that "teaching-psychology" or "psychological-education" would be better.

I would use a tag with "...-of-psychology" in it, that way it is most clear. I prefer "education-of-...", because that is more general than teaching alone. It would include internships, training analysis (a therapy undergone as part of the education as psychotherapist) etc.

I've merged the four other teaching tag questions into "teaching-of-psychology" given that it was unclear that the teaching tag was intended only for teaching psychology. My main concern about education-in-psychology or education-of-psychology is that it looks very similar to "educational-psychology", but I'm not too fussed on the details as long as it is clear which is which.
